# Items disappearing from workshop?

Tags: fallout-4

In my workshop in Sanctuary items have started disappearing. All items that include adhesive, aluminum, or screws have disappeared. I know I haven't done any crafting since the game-save where they were in my workshop inventory.

Why would this happen, and is there a way to recover the missing items?

Comment: Do you have any mods installed? Is this on PC, xbox, etc? Do you have any manufacturing setups running? I once left a conveyor belt system running and accidentally made 200+ pipe pistols..

Comment: @MeesterTeem I have no mods installed, it is PC, and nothing is set up to use components in any way.

Comment: Just to doublecheck, you didn't do any crafting at other settlements either, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've read in other questions that [settlers can steal your stuff](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/248035/how-to-make-the-settlers-steal-my-stuff/248036#248036) so I'd expect that is the issue, since you've mentioned in the comments that there's no mods/workshops running.

Answer (score 2):

I've just experienced the same thing. All my materials are stored in one settlement, Hangman's Alley. I regularly empty my workshop benches and place all junk in Hangman's Alley Workbench because of the scavenging cap (once your workshop has (i believe) 240 items your settlers stop scavenging).

My answer to your question is either one of three things.

1. Do you store dropped weapons/armor in your workbench to increase settlement build size? Cause that will mess with the games memory and cause glitches.
2. Raiders raided you. I've never heard of this, but I just witnessed it. My Hangman's Alley was attacked, I ignored it because I play survival and was no where near plus i only have a water pump there with 'The Scribe' as my only settler (no defenses). When I made my way back there was a dead raider (that I guess the scribe killed) by my weapons, armor, ammo and food crates and workbench. In her inventory was one of my personalized legendary radium riffles that I custom named 'Hell-fire'....shortly after i realized that over 400 aluminum and 700 adhesive was missing.
3. It's Fucking Bethesda.

Comment: Any more information on that scavenged item number cap? That jives with what I've seen personally, but I've certainly never measured it.

Comment: #2 is interesting. Makes sense, but never had that happen before (that I *noticed*...).